# Map scalar property to foreign key table with entity framework code first

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

Say I have a simple relationship like this:

Table: **Media**, Columns: `Id, Url, MediaTypeId (fk -> MediaType)`

Table: **MediaType**, Columns: `Id, Name`

Class: **Media** (`Id, Url, Name`)

How do I configure Entity Framework (fluent api) to map the `Name` property directly to the value of the `MediaType` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as I know, there is no way to do that. Instead you can access Name property of the MediaType class via Media.MediaType.Name as below

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Media m = new Media();
            var name = m.MediaType.Name;
        }
    }

    public class Media
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public MediaType MediaType { get; set; }
    }

    public class MediaType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that's the way i've done it before. But in the application the mediatype.id is never used. So it feels a bit oversized for me to keep an extra complex property in the app when i only need the name.

Comment: @raisr: You never create or update `Media`? If not you can create database view and map the view.

Comment: Yes, i never create `Media` or `MediaType` elements in code. But creating a db view just to map a single property seems a bit overkill to me. If there is no way to solve this problem via an ef mapping i'll use a `MediaType` navigation property.

Comment: Because there is no further answer, the simplest solution is rays.